# extra characters added in rabbitmq messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to work on a  simple rabbitMQ instance of producer and consumer.

```
public void newCustomerToQueue(Custom custom) throws Exception{

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    CustomWrap custom= new CustomWrap();
    custom.setname(custom.getname());

    String jsonString;
    try {
        jsonString = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(custom);
       // System.out.println(jsonString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); //todo
    }


    try {
        channel.basicPublish("",TASK_QUEUE_NAME, null, SerializationUtils.serialize(jsonString));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + jsonString + "'");     
}
```

And my receiving class is as follows:

```
public void ReceiveLead() throws Exception{

    final String TASK_QUEUE_NAME = "task_queue";
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    final com.rabbitmq.client.Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    final Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");
    channel.basicQos(1);

    final Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Recieved" +message);

            try {
              byte[] body1 = message.getBytes();
              System.out.println("inside"+new String(body1));

            doWork(body1);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println(" [x] Done");
                channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
            }          
        }
    };

    channel.basicConsume(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);   

}
```

The problem is when i receive this particular message extra characters are getting appended in my string Example:
Received '?? t ={"Name":"string"}'
Can somebody please help me out I cant seem to find why this is happening!!

Comment: Probably, it happens because you use `SerializationUtils.serialize`. Try to convert string to bytes: `jsonString.getBytes()`

Comment: In that case it throws an exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: and my message is never passed to the reciever

Comment: You need to use the same encoding `jsonString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`

Comment: Thank you it works now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string with payload should be converted to the array of bytes using the UTF-8 encoding:

```
jsonString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The `SerializationUtils.serialize` should not be used in this case, because it adds additional metadata about the serialized object.